# React Native: Library to record the output of the audio board

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I wanted to know if they know any bookstore to record the output of the audio card of the cell phone. The majority that I found recorded the microphone or through the speakers.
It would be very helpful if you know a library that can solve this.
Thank you very much, I'm waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[react-native-audio](https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio) might help you, it has the option to record and save the audio

Comment: Thank you very much, I will review it.